# Extra 0 print in float on windows

Tags: c++, linux, g++

I have a  program which shows a different print (an extra  0 on windows) and i am trying to make it same as linux .
On windows using Visual studio 2012 . On linux using g++ v4.8.3

Any sugegstion .

I have created a small program to showcase problem that I am facing ...

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

 float f = -1e-14;
 printf("\n\n  \t Lets print the float value  -1e-14  as  [%9.3g]  \n\n\n\n",f);  

return 0;
}
```

**On linux :**

```
/home/mag>./a.out


         Lets print the float value  -1e-14  as  [   -1e-14]
```

**On windows :(notice extra 0 in -1e-014)**

```
         Lets print the float value  -1e-14  as  [  -1e-014]
```

Reason why I am trying to make it same is because I am debugging some output from windows and linux and huge amount of differences between outputs of windows and linux are due to the problem stated above and I am missing important differences because of these .

Comment: You are building it with GCC in both cases?

Comment: On windows using Visual studio 2012 . On linux using g++ v4.8.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call [`_set_output_format(_TWO_DIGIT_EXPONENT)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0fatw238(v=vs.110).aspx) first to cause `printf()` to use two-digit exponents with VS2012.

Comment: Note that this is no longer available in Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Was the discrepancy resolved in that version?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara From the documentation for _set_output_format, 2015 version, it looks like they got rid of this and the exponents will always be 3 digits.

Comment: _set_output_format( _TWO_DIGIT_EXPONENT ) solved my problem . But what would be a solution on 2015 ?

Comment: To migrate to GCC >.>